# Integrate $\log_2(1+b(ax^2+c)^{-2})$

Tags: integration

I am wondering how to calculate $\int \log_2(1+b(ax^2+c)^{-2})$, where $a,b,c>0$.

I have used [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to calculate it, and the answer is like
[image: The result from wolframalpha]

While it gives me a nice result, I am wondering how to get it. (Wolfram|Alpha does not provide Step-by-Step Solution for this problem)

Answer:

### Most results are from the answer of @Claude Leibovici, and part is from the suggestion of @Robert Z. Thanks for their help.

$$
 \int\log_2 \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{\log\left(2\right)}\int\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right)\,dx
$$
We denote $I \triangleq \int\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right)\,dx$. Use integration by parts to get rid of the logarithm,
$$
 u\triangleq\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right)\implies du=-\frac{4 a b x}{\left(a x^2+c\right) \left(\left(a x^2+c\right)^2+b\right)}
$$
$$I=x\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right)+\int\frac{4 a b x^2}{\left(a x^2+c\right) \left(\left(a x^2+c\right)^2+b\right)}\,dx$$
Now, partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{4 a b x^2}{\left(a x^2+c\right) \left(\left(a x^2+c\right)^2+b\right)}=\frac{4 \left(a c x^2+b+c^2\right)}{a^2 x^4+2 a c x^2+b+c^2}-\frac{4 c}{a x^2+c}$$
Now, factor the denominator
$$a^2 x^4+2 a c x^2+b+c^2=a^2\left(x^2+\frac{c+ \sqrt{-b}}{a}\right) \left(x^2+\frac{c- \sqrt{-b}}{a}\right)$$
$$\frac{4 \left(a c x^2+b+c^2\right)}{a^2 x^4+2 a c x^2+b+c^2} = \frac{2 c+2 \sqrt{-b}}{a x^2+c+ \sqrt{-b}} + \frac{2c-2 \sqrt{-b}}{a x^2+ c- \sqrt{-b}} = \frac{2}{\frac{a}{c+ \sqrt{-b}} x^2+1} + \frac{2}{\frac{a}{c- \sqrt{-b}} x^2+1}$$
Thus
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  I = x\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right) 
  &+ 2  \sqrt{ \frac{ c+\sqrt{-b} }{a} } \tan^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{c+\sqrt{-b}}} x \right)\\
  &+ 2  \sqrt{ \frac{ c-\sqrt{-b} }{a} } \tan^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{c-\sqrt{-b}}} x \right)\\
  &-  4 \sqrt{ \frac{c}{a} } \tan^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}} x \right)
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Integration by parts transforms the logarithmic function in a rational one which can be integrated by partial fraction decomposition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It brings me great insights into the related question.

Comment: To get step by step solution of an integral, try https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: Genius! Very thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right)\,dx$$ Use integration by parts to get rid of the logarithm
$$u=\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right)\implies du=-\frac{4 a b x}{\left(a x^2+c\right) \left(\left(a x^2+c\right)^2+b\right)}$$
$$I=x\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^2}\right)+\int\frac{4 a b x^2}{\left(a x^2+c\right) \left(\left(a x^2+c\right)^2+b\right)}\,dx$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{4 a b x^2}{\left(a x^2+c\right) \left(\left(a x^2+c\right)^2+b\right)}=\frac{4 \left(a c x^2+b+c^2\right)}{a^2 x^4+2 a c x^2+b+c^2}-\frac{4 c}{a x^2+c}$$
Now, factor the denominator
$$a^2 x^4+2 a c x^2+b+c^2=a^2\left(x^2+\frac{c+i \sqrt{b}}{a}\right) \left(x^2+\frac{c-i \sqrt{b}}{a}\right)$$ Partial fractions again .....

**Edit**

Considering the more general case of
$$I_d=\int\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^d}\right)\,dx$$ where $d$ is an integer (if not, no hope for any result). As you wrote in comment
$$I_d=x\log \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^d}\right)+2abd \int\frac{x^2}{\left(b + \left(ax^2+c\right)^d\right)\left(ax^2+c\right)}\,dx$$ The denominator is a polynomial of degree $(d+1)$ in $x^2$ which can be written as
$$\left(b + \left(ax^2+c\right)^d\right)\left(ax^2+c\right)=a^{d+1} \prod_{i=1}^{d+1} (x^2-r_i)$$ where the $r_i$'s are the roots of the polynomial. So, partial fraction decomposition will give
$$2abd \int\frac{x^2}{\left(b + \left(ax^2+c\right)^d\right)\left(ax^2+c\right)}\,dx=\frac {2bd}{a^d}\,\sum_{i=1}^{d+1}\alpha_i \int \frac {dx}{x^2-r_i}$$ which does not make much problem (as long as you found the $r_i$'s and the $\alpha_i$'s (the latest depending on the former).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It well solved my confusion. If possible, please allow me to complete the remained results by following your answer.

Comment: @LeeWhite. Just continue. I am sure that you will make it. Don't disappoint me, please. Cheers :-)

Comment: I add the results to the position of the question description. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, for some cases when the partial fraction decomposition is hard to do, does this kind of method still work? For example, the problem changes to $ \int\log_2 \left(1+\frac{b}{\left(a x^2+c\right)^d}\right)\,dx$, $d = 50$, $d = 1.23$ or generally $d >0$.

Comment: @LeeWhite. Why do you want me to cry ?

Comment: Sorry, sir. I still do not finish the extension question, that is,
$$\int \log \left(1 + \frac{b}{\left( ax^2+c\right)^d}\right)$$
According to the method mentioned above, using integration by parts, we have 
$$I = xlog\left(1+\frac{b}{\left( ax^2+c\right)^d}\right) + \int v dx$$
$$v = \frac{\left(ax^2+c\right)^d}{b + \left(ax^2+c\right)^d}\left(b d\right)\frac{2ax}{\left(ax^2+c\right)^{d+1}} x= 2abd \frac{x^2}{\left(b + \left(ax^2+c\right)^d\right)\left(ax^2+c\right)}$$
It's hard me for how to decompose $v$.

Comment: I get it. Very thanks for your help.